# Find and Replace Inside a Text File referring to the file name

Tags: search, replace, find, notepad++

What's the simplest way to do a find and replace for a given input string from filename,

Example:
filename is

```
abc.txt
```

Find inside text file:

```
Name = "xyz",
Nametitle = "xyz",
```

and replace to:

```
Name = "abc",
Nametitle = "abc",
```

What the easiest way to achieve my goal? 
Can i use notepad++?

Comment: absolutely use notepad++

Comment: how to make batch for search and replace, i have plenty files to change, how to change it with notepad++.

Comment: In the search dialog there is a tab to 'Find in Files'.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is your first question on stackoverflow. Perhaps you are new to programming? But your question isn't really a programming question. But that is ok.

Sure, use notepad++: open the options for search and replace.
Add in the word you want to find, and the word you want to replace it with.
Do this for each word you want to replace.

Be sure to check the option to make it search for only the entire word: Otherwise your xyz could also match xyzFoo. And you might not want to replace it with abcFoo.

Also look for the option to search with case sensitivity (based on your preferences really).

Notepad++ is a fine editor if you are on windows. On a mac there are a myriad other options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes i'm not a programmer,, just want to learn something new, 
the situation is , let say i have 500 file that have different name, 
is to time consuming to change it one by one, can i use notepad++ for batch automaticaly?
Example:

abc.txt
Name = "xyz",
Nametitle = "xyz",
replace to:
Name = "abc",
Nametitle = "abc",


bca.txt
Name = "xyz",
Nametitle = "xyz",
replace to:
Name = "bca",
Nametitle = "bca",


dfe.txt
Name = "xyz",
Nametitle = "xyz",
replace to:
Name = "dfe",
Nametitle = "dfe",


Can you suggest me what kind of software that i can use for that purpose?